# Не работает Binder

Tags: android

Написал Binder для SimpleCursorAdapter. Установил его. Установил SimpleCursorAdapter в ListView. Код входит в Binder. Это видно по логам. Но картинку с помощью UniversalImageLoader(сторонняя библиотека) не ставит.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DB db;
SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
Cursor cursor;
ListView listView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Executor downloadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    int memClass = am.getMemoryClass();
    final int memoryCacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .taskExecutor(downloadExecutor)
            .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize)) // 2 Mb
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(this, 5 * 1000, 30 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (30 s)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    cursor = db.getAllData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_PREV_IMG, DB.COLUMN_HEADER, DB.COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT, DB.COLUMN_DATE };
    int[] to = new int[] {  R.id.prev_img, R.id.tvHeader, R.id.tvShortText, R.id.tvDate };

    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    sca.setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
    listView.setAdapter(sca);

    ItemListener itemClickListener = new ItemListener();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}

private static class MyBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int i) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.prev_img) {
            String line = c.getString(3);
            Log.d("myLogs", "Внутри биндера ^^");
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://storage/emulated/0/AndroidTest/data/ru.kavyrshinr.p0881_asynctaskresult/‌​Image/myImage2.jpg", (ImageView) view);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "" + id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailedActivity.EXTRA_ITEM_NO, (int) id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

В логи пишет что файла нет. Хотя он есть

Comment: А вот если перекинуть картинку в папку Download то ок.

Comment: Вы уверены что путь к файлу корректный?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Проверил несколько раз. Да. Но стоит заметить что тот путь создавало другое приложение. Может поэтому?